# jsPlumb incrase speed execution

Tags: jquery, algorithm, jsplumb

I am using jsPlumb library to draw (connect) some divs. The number of divs is dynamic and can go up to 2000 divs. I am using the following recursive approach to draw the line:

```
connectGraphNodes: function(jsp_o, children, level){
    var nr_of_children, i=0;

    nr_of_children = children.length;
    for(i=0; i<nr_of_children; i++){
        if(!this.isPropertyEmpty(children[i]['id']) && !this.isPropertyEmpty(children[i]['name'])){
            // Connect child node with node
            jsp_o.connect({ 
                source: 'es-org-graph-box-' + children[i]['parent'], 
                target: 'es-org-graph-box-' + children[i]['id'],
               overlays:[
                    [ "Label", {
                            label: children[i]['percentage']+'%', id:"label",
                            location: 1                                
                        }
                    ]
                ]   
            });

            if(this.isSet(children[i]['children']) && children[i]['children'].length > 0){
                level++;
                // Run recurence function for child-nodes
                jsp_o.setSuspendDrawing(true);
                this.connectGraphNodes(jsp_o, children[i]['children'], level);
                jsp_o.setSuspendDrawing(false, true);
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

My problem is that for a number bigger than 100 the loading time is very high and somethimes google chrome pops up a close tab option. Is there any improvement that i can make to my approach or the jsPlumb is that slow ?

Comment: jsPlumb has a method to suspend drawings which is recommended for "when you have a lot of connections to make or endpoints to register":  http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/files/jsPlumb-1.4.1-apidoc.html#jsPlumb.setSuspendDrawing

Answer (score 1):

Like Rich already mentioned, you have to make use of the

```
jsPlumb.setSuspendDrawing();
```

method

try this:

```
connectGraphNodes: function(jsp_o, children, level){
    var nr_of_children, i=0;

    nr_of_children = children.length;
    //start of suspend drawing
    jsPlumb.setSuspendDrawing(true);
    for(i=0; i<nr_of_children; i++){
        if(!this.isPropertyEmpty(children[i]['id']) && !this.isPropertyEmpty(children[i]['name'])){
            // Connect child node with node
            jsp_o.connect({ 
                source: 'es-org-graph-box-' + children[i]['parent'], 
                target: 'es-org-graph-box-' + children[i]['id'],
               overlays:[
                    [ "Label", {
                            label: children[i]['percentage']+'%', id:"label",
                            location: 1                                
                        }
                    ]
                ]   
            });

            if(this.isSet(children[i]['children']) && children[i]['children'].length > 0){
                level++;
                // Run recurence function for child-nodes
                jsp_o.setSuspendDrawing(true);
                this.connectGraphNodes(jsp_o, children[i]['children'], level);
                jsp_o.setSuspendDrawing(false, true);
            }
        }            
    }
    //end of suspend drawing
    jsPlumb.setSuspendDrawing(false,true);
}
```